# Find the possible routes using Recursion in Python. Note [ I need this to be done without any module]

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, recursion

```
locations = ["loc1", "loc2", "loc3", "loc4", "loc5"]
```

Suppose this is the list of some given locations now I want to make all the possible arrangements but make sure that all arrangements should be with the `loc1` at the fixed place.
e. g

```
["loc1", "loc3", "loc2", "loc4", "loc5"]
["loc1", "loc3", "loc4", "loc2", "loc5"]
```

and so on..
can you please tell me how the algorithm looks like for this specific problem using recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
from itertools import permutations
locations = ["loc1", "loc2", "loc3", "loc4", "loc5"]

permutated_locations = [[locations[0]] + list(i) for i in permutations(locations[1:])]

for l in permutated_locations:
    print(l)
```

Output:

```
['loc1', 'loc2', 'loc5', 'loc4', 'loc3']
['loc1', 'loc3', 'loc2', 'loc4', 'loc5']
['loc1', 'loc3', 'loc2', 'loc5', 'loc4']
['loc1', 'loc3', 'loc4', 'loc2', 'loc5']
['loc1', 'loc3', 'loc4', 'loc5', 'loc2']
['loc1', 'loc3', 'loc5', 'loc2', 'loc4']
['loc1', 'loc3', 'loc5', 'loc4', 'loc2']
['loc1', 'loc4', 'loc2', 'loc3', 'loc5']
['loc1', 'loc4', 'loc2', 'loc5', 'loc3']
['loc1', 'loc4', 'loc3', 'loc2', 'loc5']
['loc1', 'loc4', 'loc3', 'loc5', 'loc2']
['loc1', 'loc4', 'loc5', 'loc2', 'loc3']
['loc1', 'loc4', 'loc5', 'loc3', 'loc2']
['loc1', 'loc5', 'loc2', 'loc3', 'loc4']
['loc1', 'loc5', 'loc2', 'loc4', 'loc3']
['loc1', 'loc5', 'loc3', 'loc2', 'loc4']
['loc1', 'loc5', 'loc3', 'loc4', 'loc2']
['loc1', 'loc5', 'loc4', 'loc2', 'loc3']
['loc1', 'loc5', 'loc4', 'loc3', 'loc2']
```